# Inserting an automatically generated index from a table into another table

Tags: mysql, sql

Say we have two tables:

- `table1 (id, name, type)` where `id` is a primary key, and auto-incremented
- `table2 (item_id, place)` where `item_id` refers to `id` in  `table1`

I want to do the following:

```
insert into table1(name, type) values (y, z);
```

Assuming that that query would assign `id=x` for that row, then:

```
insert into table2(item_id, place) values (x, w);
```

How could I do that?
In other words, how could I get the `id` of the row that has just been added?

Comment: Are you doing this with mysql alone? Is there any language involved?

Comment: Single row inserts or sets? Same source eg bcp or staging table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
insert into table1(name, type) values (y, z);
insert into table2(item_id, place) values (LAST_INSERT_ID() , w);
```

The [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) will do this for you. Most programming languages have a special function that call this for you, but it works in pure MySQL.

Comment: It is a web script, what if two users using the page in the same time, the first inserted the values then the second user inserted after him , does that means that LAST_INSERT_ID() would return the inserted value by the second user, or the first "current"??

Comment: The variable works 'per connection', so as long as you're not sharing connections between users, this won't happen.