# LAST_INSERT_ID() how it works at multi-users environment

Tags: php, mysql

check that question first:
[Inserting an automatically generated index from a table into another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834448/inserting-an-automatically-generated-index-from-a-table-into-another-table)
I got that this function "LAST_INSERT_ID()" do the required
the question is: I'm using that in a php script, what if some user inserted data in "table1" and before he insert the "id" into "table2"  another user inserted data into "table1"...then which "id" would the function retrieve for the first user, his id or the id of the second user "the last one"??
I wish to retrieve the "id" that the user himself "the first user" inserted, so if it doesn't achieve that how to do it??

Answer (score 30, accepted):

LAST_INSERT_ID() gives you the last autogenerated id on the connection you execute it on, it does not return the last insert id globally produced by the MySQL server.

Comment: Also it's (very) good practice to call it right after the query. This way you just can't be wrong. If you have issues in doing that, you may want to rethink your code.

Comment: Note: every MySQL connection belongs to exactly one user, so there is a 1-to-1 relation. In this case, `lastInsertId` would always return user's last autogenerated id. But for **shared MySQL connection** you must use **transaction** to get the correct `lastInsertId` as shared connection have 1-to-N relation.

Answer (score -2):

NEVER ever use lastInsertId() with PostgreSQL sequences, ESPECIALLY when your application's insert/update load is high. PostgreSQL sequences are non-transactional (a natural design feature to avoid exclusive locking which otherwise produces unacceptable performance). This means that any concurrent transaction incrementing the same sequence will render the value returned by lastInsertId() invalid with respect to the last insert by your transaction. Example:

```
Transaction 1 inserts with nextval('some_seq') yielding 100;
Concurrent transaction 2 inserts with nextval('some_seq') yielding 101;
Transaction 1 calls lastInsertId(), expecting 100, BUT GETS 101.
```

This PDO method is braindead for PostgreSQL, always use INSERT ... RETURNING instead. Regards.

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

Comment: How is this answering the question? The question is about the MySQL function [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) and it is clearly tagged [tag:mysql] and not `postgresql`.