# PDO Last Insert ID always the right one?

Tags: php, pdo

I have the following code:

```
<?
$query =$db->prepare("INSERT INTO a_table (id, a_field) VALUES ('', (:a_field)");
$query->bindParam(":a_field", $a_value);
$query->execute();
$last_id = $db->lastInsertId('a_table');
?>
```

What I want to ask is this. Imagine when two people load the page at exactly the same time, is it a possible danger that the other persons query is inserted before the last ID is retrieved, mixing up the IDs?

Comment: No, there will be no conflict. The insert id is dependent upon the connection, and each page load will establish a new connection.

Comment: Depends on the underlying database. If it's mysql, PDO will simply be calling the mysql last_insert_id() API function, which guarantees that the returned ID is the ID generated by the last insert query performed by your PDO connection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LAST_INSERT_ID() how it works at multi-users environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835677/last-insert-id-how-it-works-at-multi-users-environment)

Comment: It is mysql, so I understand I'm safe. Many thanks! Michael, sorry, didn't find the post you are referring to...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, this situation is impossible.
Method $db->lastInsertId() returns last inserted id for this DB conection. In other page will be another connection and another last inserted id.

Answer (score 6):

PDO will return you the last ID inserted by the current active database connection.

Answer (score 1):

Just faced following situation

Have file `post.php` which includes another file (like `insert.php`).

Whole code to insert in mysql is located in `insert.php`

In `insert.php` is code `$id_of_inserted_row = $db->lastInsertId();`

Then in `insert.php` is `echo $id_of_inserted_row;` which shows correct value.

But `echo $id_of_inserted_row;` in `post.php` shows incorrect value (as i see shows 7 numbers less than actual value). I do not understand why, just need to take into account.

**Update**

Sorry, above written was because inserted in two tables and mistakenly used the same `$id_of_inserted_row = $db->lastInsertId();` for both tables.

So i have the same conclusion as in other answers: `lastInsertId()` gets id of last inserted row.

Faced situation. I inserted 2 rows in mysql. In such case i see that lastInsertId() is id of the first inserted row (not the last). Do not understand why...
Found answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574752/2118559

> Important If you insert multiple rows using a single INSERT statement, LAST_INSERT_ID() returns the value generated for the first inserted row only. The reason for this is to make it possible to reproduce easily the same INSERT statement against some other server.